# Print Status Error

Tags: python, printing, pywin32

Right now, I am enumerating a list of printers and jobs using `win32print` and I get the status of jobs.

```
for printStats in printers:

    handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(printStats[2])
    queued = win32print.EnumJobs(handle, 0, -1, 1)


    for printJob in queued:

        username = printJob['pUserName']
        computer = printJob['pMachineName']
        document = printJob['pDocument']
        identity = printJob['JobId']


        # get the detailed status description of the current print

        jobstate = win32print.GetJob(handle, identity, 2)['Status']
```

For some reason in the infinite `while` loop, the program throws this error about getting the job status.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Malik\Desktop\Stem\2.0\adding.py", line 53, in <module>
    jobstate = win32print.GetJob(handle, identity, 2)['Status']
error: (87, 'GetJob', 'The parameter is incorrect.')
```

Any ideas as to why that is happening? What can I do to fix this error to get the status of the print job?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to determine the reason for this error recently. The software responded to changes in printer queues, calling GetJob for all jobs found. Without going into details about the process, I can say that the reason why I was observing the error was because by the time GetJob was called for certain jobs they had been printed and removed from the queue. That is, calling GetJob for a job that does not exist will result in a "The parameter is incorrect" error, presumably because the parameter (job id) is incorrect. I think Microsoft could have returned a more specific error and saved a lot of people a lot of time. Of course, your case may be different.

Comment: Actually, in my python 2.7 code, getjob does not fail with this error when the job has completed and deleted itself, it works correctly.  However, as I was converting my code to python 3.7, I am now getting that same error.  I think there is a bug in win32print getjob when the job has been deleted.  Anyone else have more information?